# How to close a trade for sure in MQL4/MT4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, forex, mt4

I have an EA with closes a trade on button click

```
//void CloseCurrentTrade(). It's called after successfull OrderSelect
int orderType = OrderType();
double price;
if (orderType == OP_BUY)
    price = return MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID);
else if (orderType == OP_SELL)
    price = return MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK);
else
    return;
int slippage = 20;
bool closed = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), price, slippage);
if (closed)
    return;
int lastError = GetLastError();
```

Sometimes it closes the trade and sometimes it returns error #129 (Invalid price). I can't figure out why. Most of the cases people just misuse bid/ask or don't have enouth slippage. I've try to use slippage up to 200, still the same error. Some EA's just try to close it several times (and it looks like a hack for me), but it does not help as well. There are some mentions that you need to call RefreshRates() before bid/ask, but documentaion says that you don't need to do that for MarketInfo.

I've run out of ideas what it could be. Why it can happen and how to avoid that? I'm testing it on FXCM Demo (if it is the case).

Comment: You can use `OrderClosePrice()` instead of bid or ask. The best way seems to try to close the ticket several times, if failed - `Sleep(25)` and `RefreshRates()` after that.

Comment: OrderClosePrice() is equial to Bid/Ask I'm using when it fails

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that you've selected the order properly, and try to use `OrderClosePrice` where possible(this will eliminate the need for checking the `OP_SELL`/`OP_BUY`)

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Close the latest order for this current symbol                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CloseCurrentTrade()
  {
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
      if(!OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)) continue;
      if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol()) continue;
      if(OrderMagicNumber()!=MagicNum) continue; // if there is no magic number set, then no need for this(manual orders)
      if(OrderType()>OP_SELL) continue;

      if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderClosePrice(),Slippage))
         Print("Error in Closing the Order, Error : ",ErrorDescription(GetLastError()));

      break; // assuming you want to close the latest trade only, exit the order closing loop
     }
  }
```

Also note that your broker might have restrictions on how far the closing price must be from the Order Opened price and other levels(sl/tp), in order to close an order. [Refer here](https://book.mql4.com/appendix/limits)

Answer (score 0):

Print and compare `Ask/Bid` && `price` when `closed!=true`. Beware that `MarketInfo` mode data is stored at `Ask/Bid` predefined variables already, so you can eliminate that if you `OrderSelect` in current symbol.

Comment: Ask/Bid are cached values. Basically, MarketInfo is equal to RefreshRates() + Ask/Bid. And when it fails Ask/Bid is equal to the price I'm using to close the trade.